# linux + How to verify hardware or software RAID?

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive, software-raid, hardware-raid

Is it possible to know by Linux command if my RAID is HW or SW RAID?

for example in my machine - BLADE from dell MANUFACTURE

by /ptoc/mdstat seems my RAID is "SW RAID" ?

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sdr2[1] sdq2[0]
  390054912 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
  bitmap: 1/3 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sdr1[1] sdq1[0]
  524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
  bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

but how to absolutely know if my RAID is SW or HW ? BY WHICH COMMAND LINE?

from lsblk

```
lsblk

vg00-lv_root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
└─md1          9:1    0   372G  0 raid1
├─sdq2      65:2    0 372.1G  0 part
│ └─sdq     65:0    0 372.6G  0 disk
└─sdr2      65:18   0 372.1G  0 part
  └─sdr     65:16   0 372.6G  0 disk
vg00-lv_swap 253:1    0    16G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
└─md1          9:1    0   372G  0 raid1
├─sdq2      65:2    0 372.1G  0 part
│ └─sdq     65:0    0 372.6G  0 disk
└─sdr2      65:18   0 372.1G  0 part
  └─sdr     65:16   0 372.6G  0 disk
vg00-lv_var  253:2    0   100G  0 lvm   /var
 └─md1          9:1    0   372G  0 raid1
 ├─sdq2      65:2    0 372.1G  0 part
 │ └─sdq     65:0    0 372.6G  0 disk
 └─sdr2      65:18   0 372.1G  0 part
    └─sdr     65:16   0 372.6G  0 disk



  mdadm --detail /dev/md1
  /dev/md1:
       Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Mon Jun 26 13:14:03 2017
    Raid Level : raid1
    Array Size : 390054912 (371.99 GiB 399.42 GB)
    Used Dev Size : 390054912 (371.99 GiB 399.42 GB)
    Raid Devices : 2
    Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

   Update Time : Sun Jul  9 12:45:29 2017
         State : clean
  Active Devices : 2
  Working Devices : 2
  Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Name : localhost:1
         UUID : b13eee32:f5894d0c:23aaf608:a67290c9
         Events : 605

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
      0      65        2        0      active sync   /dev/sdq2
      1      65       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdr2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mdX` devices shown in the output of `/proc/mdstat` are software raid devices created `mdadm`. You can have software raid configured on your machine.

From the output, it is clear you have raid1 configured. To get more information, you can use `mdadm --detail /dev/mdX`.

Having software raid configured on your machine does not mean you don't have a hardware raid configured also (which may or may not make sense!).

Comment: so for summary can we use this syntax in order to verify SW or HW RAID - [[ ` cat /proc/mdstat | grep -c md ` -eq 2 ]] && echo "SW RAID" || echo "HW RAID"

Comment: from mdadm --detail /dev/md1 output ( as I already edit in my question  ) , what is the values from the command that show this is SW configuration ?

Comment: @shalom: No specific value is required. It is just having such devices `mdX` under `/proc/mdstat`.

Comment: At the risk of nitpicking, /proc/mdstat can only tell if you are or are not using SW RAID.  You can make no inferences about HW RAID at all from /proc/mdstat.  If you REALLY want to be sure about HW RAID, and have a known set of possible hw possibilities, you could write a script to check for the existence configuration/status utilities and execute them if found.  Or possibly query a management processor (BMC/ILO/DRAC/IPMI/etc).  Or possibly SNMP.